# MySQL Query within a query on same table

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have a table like:

```
Status | Quantity | PeriodDate
------------------------------
100    | 2        | 2013-07-02
100    | 3        | 2013-07-02
100    | 5        | 2013-07-02
100    | 3        | 2013-07-03
100    | 1        | 2013-07-03
100    | 0        | 2013-07-04
100    | 0        | 2013-07-04
100    | 5        | 2013-07-04
100    | 6        | 2013-07-05
100    | 4        | 2013-07-06
100    | 8        | 2013-07-06
```

And I need to select data such that it displays the count of Quantity for each distinct dates in a range. I would have thought I could do something to the tune of:

```
SELECT DISTINCT PeriodDate, SUM(Quantity) as TotalQuantity where PeriodDate BETWEEN '2013-07-02' AND '2013-07-04'
```

But this returns one row with the entire sum of all quantities.

I'm after something like:

```
TotalQuantity | PeriodDate
--------------------------
10            | 2013-07-02
4             | 2013-07-03
5             | 2013-07-04
6             | 2013-07-05
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT PeriodDate, 
       SUM(Quantity) as TotalQuantity 
from your_table
where PeriodDate BETWEEN '2013-07-02' AND '2013-07-05'
group by PeriodDate
```

Answer (score 3):

Distinct works on both `PeriodDate` and `TotalQuantity`. Instead of using `DISTINCT`, you need to use `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT PeriodDate, SUM(Quantity) as TotalQuantity 
FROM ???
WHERE PeriodDate BETWEEN '2013-07-02' AND '2013-07-04'
GROUP BY PeriodDate
```

Explaination: Distinct is used to eliminate duplicate rows in a resultset.

Further explaination: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-distinct.aspx

Comment: although after jeurgen's answer, your version clarifies the WHY (hence my upvote)